# spray-can webservice graceful shutdown

Tags: web-services, scala, akka, spray

I have **spray.io** based webservice, it runs as standalone jar (I use `sbt assembly` and then just `java -jar myws.jar`). It has pretty the same bootsrap as in spray examples, like this:

```
/** Bootstrap */
object Boot extends App {
   // we need an ActorSystem to host our application in
   implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

   // create and start our service actor
   val service = system.actorOf(Props[MyServiceActor], "my-ws-service")

   implicit val timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)

   CLIOptionsParser.parse(args, CLIOptionsConfig()) map { config =>
     // start a new HTTP server
     IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = config.interface, port = config.port)
   }
}
```

Now I just run the process in the backgroud with `java -jar my-service "$@" &` and stop with `kill -9 pid`.

I'd like to stop my webservice gracefully, meaning that it finishes open connections and refuses new ones.

Spray-can page on [github](https://github.com/spray/spray-can#shutting-down-1) recommends `to send it an Akka PoisonPill message`. Ideally I'd like to initiate it from command line, as simple as possible. I thought maybe to attach one more HTTP server instance bound to localhost only, and having some rest methods to stop, and maybe diagnose the webservice. Is it feasible? What are the other options?

**UPDATE**:
I added what I can imagine have to work, based on answers, but it seems not to, at least I've never seen any message I expected to see in stdout or log. Actually, I've tried in variations HttpUnbind, PoisonPill, together and by one. May anyone with a hard akka eye look at this? PS. The hook itself is called successfully, checked it. Signal I send to jvm is SIGTERM.

```
/* Simple reaper actor */
class Reaper(refs: ActorRef*) extends Actor {
  private val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  val watched = ArrayBuffer(refs: _*)

  refs foreach context.watch

  final def receive = {
    case Terminated(ref) =>
      watched -= ref
      log.info(s"Terminated($ref)")
      println(s"Terminated($ref)")
      if (watched.isEmpty) {
        log.info("Shutting dow the system")
        println("Shutting dow the system")
        system.shutdown()
      }
  }
}


// termination hook to gracefully shutdown the service
Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  override def run() = {
    val reaper = system.actorOf(Props(new Reaper(IO(Http), service)))
    //IO(Http) ? Http.Unbind(5.minutes)
    IO(Http) ! PoisonPill
  }
})
```

**UPDATE2**: So, somehow it works, namely - when PoisonPill is sent all current HTTP connections got closed. But I'd rather to stop receiveing new connections, and wait for open to return response and close.

**VERDICT**: It seems that akka has its own hook, because, despite my hook gets executed, actors got killed and all connections got closed without my actions. If someone will offer solution with JVM shutdown hook it will be great. I suggest that this is important problem, and very sadly it has no any good recipe online. For a meanwhile I will try to implement graceful shutdown using tcp/http.

Comment: You can use the `Http.Unbind` message to tell the server to stop listening for new connections and closing open connections after a timeout. See http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.1/spray-can/http-server/#starting-and-stopping. Having some rest methods to stop is definitely possible, see this spray example (which doesn't stop gracefully, though) for an example: https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-routing/simple-routing-app/src/main/scala/spray/examples/Main.scala#L29

Comment: I try it here and there, but it seems doesn't work. Please, look at  the update.

Comment: @jrudolph I updated in question: hook fires, but akka system gets shut down by something else (maybe its own hook), and hence connections in process got closed (and client gets error that connection has been closed by remore). I want open connections to finish, and close only after this. Seems it has nothing to do with unbind itself.

Comment: Eventually I understood where my errors were, bad that nobody pointed out that sending `Unbound` to `IO(Http)` itself is useless, it should be sent to the listener.

Comment: Yes, you need to send `Http.Unbind` to all listeners and then wait for `Unbound` responses from all of them in a blocking fashion without ever returning from the `shutdownHook`, otherwise the process will be closed before the cleanup has happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I tried to use SIGTERM and JVM hook, I was in need to block the hook thread from exiting until my shutdown sequence finishes, and I simply don't know how to do it (I'm a bit inexperienced in akka, so maybe I missed some obvious solution).

What I finally did is attaching one more HTTP listener to localhost only, which has method to initiate shutdown (also it happened to be convenient for other tasks, like getting server status, triggering events in the application and such).

This can look like this (I suspect this may contain unnecessary actions, so refinements are welcome):

**In bootstrap**:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem(...)

// create and start external service actor
val service = system.actorOf(Props[MyWebServiceActor], "my-web-service")

// create internal service to manage application
val controlService = system.actorOf(Props[ControlServiceActor], "control-service")

implicit val timeout = Timeout(10.seconds)

// start a new HTTP server for external service (notifying control of HTTP listener)
IO(Http).tell(Http.Bind(service, interface = config.interface, port = config.port), controlService)

// start internal server looking at localhost
IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(controlService, interface = "127.0.0.1", port = config.controlPort)
```

**And the control service itself:**

```
class ControlServiceActor extends Actor with HttpService with ActorLogging {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  implicit val system = context.system

  /* Listener of main service */
  var listener: ActorRef = _

  def receive = {
    // this is reply from IO.Http when HTTP listener is bound
    case Http.Bound(_) =>
      listener = sender()
      context.become(mainContext)
  }

  // http api for graceful stop
  val mainContext = runRoute {
    path("stop") {
      get {
        parameter('timeout.as[Int] ? 60) { timeout =>
          complete {
            // unbind makes listener to reject new connections
            context.become(shuttingDownContext)
            log.warning(s"Stopping application within $timeout seconds...")
            context.watch(listener)
            listener ! Http.Unbind(timeout.seconds)

            "Stopping..."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Shutdown sequence
  val shuttingDownContext = ({
    // when unbound HTTP listener not accepting connections
    case Http.Unbound =>
      log.info("Webservice unbound, waiting for active connections to complete")

    // when HTTP listener terminated after unbound it has been processed all requests
    case Terminated(ref) if ref == listener =>
      log.info("Webservice finished, exiting")
      system.shutdown()
  }: Actor.Receive) orElse runRoute(complete("Shutdown in progress"))
}
```

Comment: nice solution for a dev environment! but for production you typically want something that gracefully gets to your shutdown code even when e.g. the server is rebooted (especially so if your shutdown actions are needed for keeping the rest of your environment happy, as much as that is the case)

Comment: That's true, but I couldn't have found this better solution yet.

Comment: Small typo - shouldn't that be `// Shutdown sequence`?

Comment: @dmitry Would sending a `PoisonPill` in addition to `Http.unbind` be a good idea considering spray's README page says to shut it down with a `PoisonPill`? https://github.com/spray/spray-can#shutting-down-1

Comment: @EdgeCaseBerg I recall I tried PoisonPill, it killed actors in somewhat straightforward manner, closing connections but without waiting for completion.

Answer (score 1):

`kill -9` will destroy process immediately. you can use SIGTERM (kill -15) to trigger shutdown hooks in jvm.

```
Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  def run() = {
    //here you can send PoisonPill
  }
})
```

Comment: Please, can you elaborate how in the case of SIGTERM the shutdown sequence looks? Say, JVM will run the hook, and how does it know the required processes have been completed?

Comment: something like described [here](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) (as spray is based on akka)

Comment: you can send some message to spray actors and use `become` to change behavior (stop receiving connections).

Comment: It all seems to be of no use, because on SIGTERM all is being killed by something else, and hook is useless. Or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: it works, but hook must somehow block the execution, and wait until all needful steps are fulfilled - e.g. some actors shut down, or some sequence is ended. It turned to be non-trivial and I found nothing on the web very helpul. I abandoned tries and proceeded with solution in accepted answer. Personally I hoped to implement variant with SIGTERM, but...